# MacOS 12.x Python / C++ App and Forcing x86 from an M1 Machine

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, macos, apple-m1

I am updating my MacOS  python/c++ application that ran fine on my older x86 machine now must build and run on my new M1 as well as older x86 machines. One binary library cannot be updated at this time so my hope is that I can run the whole thing transparently in x86 through Rosetta. Somewhere in the c++ builds, I must be happily making x86 compatible libraries, as intended, but when I run the python code using the default MacOS Python instance, I get the following error when loading the c++ library:

```
(mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e'))
```

How do I resolve the issue? I THINK I should able to acquire an x86 instance of Python, create a venv, and then run using the vent. Maybe I should get it [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/macos/) and then resolve how to call the new version instead of the MacOS default until I get a new venv and run against that.

How do I resolve this error in the most appropriate way?